# What happens when we put attention on something for longer time

Tags: cognitive-psychology, attention

I have noticed and it must be a common experience for many of people that when they 
put attention for extended period of time which could be as little as 15 minutes 
or could span over days something occurs a deeper understanding of the subject etc. 
This has been mentioned by great scientist like Newton etc attributing his scientific 
discoveries to ability to put attention on a subject for longer period of time.

I wanted to know if some psychologist has done some research over this area 
What exactly is this attention and what results from it. At one level it seems mysterious

Any references/books/examples etc.